# dotnet exec needs a managed .dll or .exe extension while adding Entity Framework Core (1.1.0) Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

**Error Message:**

```
PM> Add-Migration InitialDatabase
dotnet exec needs a managed .dll or .exe extension. The application specified was 'C:\Users\xxxxxx\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\TheWorld\src\TheWorld\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\TheWorld.runtimeconfig.json'
Process finished with non-zero exit code
PM>
```

Visual Studio Version: 2017 RC

**Project Dependencies :**

[image: Project Dependencies]

**Error Screenshot :**
[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Could you post an answer if you figure something out?

Comment: It worked after I installed .netcore 1.1 and changed the target framework to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem. The only thing I had to do is changing the Target Framework in the Project properties.

[Changing the framework version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7UOO.jpg)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. It turns out that the packages were expecting .netcore 1.1 but I had only .netcore 1.0 installed in my system. So, after instaling .netcore 1.1 and changing the framework, the issue was resolved. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: Thanks, again much time was saved (and I've had my share of figuring things out, so glad this at least was easy thanks to you :) )

Answer (score 1):

In VS2017RC - All I had to do was install .NetCore again using Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.NETCore.App
```

Later migration script worked and "dotnet exec needs a managed .dll or .exe extension." error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Tooling for VS and dotnet are still in preview. Try run `dotnet ef migrations add InitialDatabase` from command line in `TheWorld/src` folder.

Comment: PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet -Pre   
Install-Package : Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.1.0-preview4-final' has a package type 
'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'src\TheWorld'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageComm

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I tried installing entityframeworkcore.tools.dotnet . Error says dotnetclitool not supported by project .

Answer (score 0):

My context was deploying to AWS Lambda.

The fix was to change the `output type` to `Class Library` in the EF project (EFCore) that my lambda was using.

p.s. you might need to change it back when you run migrations etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue deploying a docker container to AWS Lambda.

I was using a custom container and not the `public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:latest`.

Because of this, the`lambda-entrypoint.sh` was getting confused about which `deps.json` to use and was trying to run `dotnet exec` on a random json file.

What ended up solving it was setting the environment variable `LAMBDA_DOTNET_MAIN_ASSEMBLY` to the main assembly name - not including `.dll`

This name should match the name of your `.csproj` file. For instance, if your program is `myDotnetExample.csproj` you would set the environment variable as:

```
LAMBDA_DOTNET_MAIN_ASSEMBLY = "myDotnetExample"
```

Once this variable was set, `lambda-entrypoint.sh` was able to find the proper file and run the program.