# Unable to generate model from database in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0, visual-studio-2017

I followed the official Microsoft tutorial for Entity Framework Core database first approach available in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db).

When I try to execute the below command to generate the model from the database:

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=Data Source=DESKTOP-COJD62N;Initial Catalog=TrainGameDB;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -context TrainGameContext -Verbose`

I am getting the following output:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
dotnet exec needs a managed .dll or .exe extension. The application specified was 'F:_IIT Level 6\UX\CW2 Backend\App2\TrainGameAPI\src\TrainGameAPI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\TrainGameAPI.runtimeconfig.json'
Process finished with non-zero exit code
```

I am using:

Visual Studio 2017 RC

SQL Server 2016 Developer

.NET Core 1.1.0 (I uninstalled version 1.0.1 and installed this)

ASP.NET Core Web API Application

Windows 10 Education

Here is the list of packages from my .csproj file (VS 2017 doesn't have a package.json file)

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.0.0" />
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257062/dotnet-exec-needs-a-managed-dll-or-exe-extension-while-adding-entity-framework

Comment: Are your sure of your scaffolding command ? It looks like a little weird to me. "Server=Data Source=DESKTOP-COJD62N;". Try with sometinh like "Server=[YOUR SERVER NAME];Database=[YOUR DATABASE NAME];[...]"

Comment: Also, don't you have some nuget package dependency errors ? You are using different version of .NET Core

Comment: @Adrien - I don't have any dependency errors, and I am sure about the connection string. I updated the nuget package to  NETCore.App to version 1.1. Even all the other packages. I get the same error when executing the command.

Comment: @OlaEkdahl - I tried the suggestion in that answer. But it is not seems to be working. I get the same error when I change the project framework to Core 1.1.0. When I try to update the nuget package NETCore.App to version 1.1.0. I am getting the same error. After updating I am not able to open the project again. Visual studio says non fetal error occurred.

Comment: @OlaEkdahl - I tried to create a new dot net core application and updated the nuget packages. Same thing happened to that. Can't open the solution again after closing the Visual Studio once.

Comment: Same error. Have you solved you problem?

Comment: are you holding everything in the same project ( API + Model )?  Make sure to set your starting project as the one containing your context